# Getting HashMap values from fragments to activity through Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I would like to use interface to implement the communicate of passing data from fragments to activity's button which contains onClick event. I can see HashMap can write the data which is valid on editText field, but those value cannot be sent to activity. it shows error and stopped once I trigger the onClick event on activity.

I was confused on the usage of the interface. The errors as below appears after trying on debugging, waste around 3 days to handle on it and still cannot be resolve. Can anyone recommend or discuss how to solve it, thank you.

The errors:

```
Error:(77, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(39, 8) error: Fragment_step_2 is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPassValueStep2() in onPassValue2
Error:(231, 32) error: method onPassValueStep1 in class Fragment_step_1 cannot be applied to given types;
required: HashMap
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(232, 32) error: method onPassValueStep2 in class Fragment_step_2 cannot be applied to given types;
required: HashMap
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(78, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(36, 8) error: Fragment_step_1 is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPassValueStep1() in onPassValue
```

[image: Calling Fragments' HashMap to activity]

Main activity:

```
public interface onPassValue{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1();
}

public interface onPassValue2{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2();
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ......
    btn_sendInsureInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //CALL here
            //Fragment_step_1.onPassValueStep1();
            //Fragment_step_2.onPassValueStep2();
            ......
        }
}
......
```

Fragment_step_1: (xxx is activity's name)

```
public class Fragment_step_1 extends Fragment implements xxx.onPassValue {
    ......
     HashMap insureApplicant = new HashMap<>(4);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context xxx){
    super.onAttach(xxx);

    /*try {
       passValue = (onPassValue) xxx;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(pingan_insure_info.toString()
                + " didn't implement onPassValue");
    }*/
}

@Override
public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1(HashMap insureResult) {
    for (Object key : insureResult.entrySet()) {
        //System.out.println(key + " fragment_1 : " + insureResult.get(key));
        System.out.println(" fragment_1 : " + key);
        Log.e("Hashmap", String.valueOf(insureResult));
    }
    return insureResult;
}
    ......
```

Fragment_step_2: (xxx is activity's name)

```
public class Fragment_step_2 extends Fragment implements xxx.onPassValue2{
......
RelativeLayout correspondence;
HashMap insureApplicant2 = new HashMap<>(3);

@Override
public void onAttach(Context pingan_insure_info){
    super.onAttach(pingan_insure_info);

    /*try {
        passValueStep2 = (onPassValueStep2) xxx;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(xxx.toString()
                + " didn't implement onPassValue");
    }*/
}

@Override
public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2(HashMap insureApplicantStep2){
    for (Object key : insureApplicantStep2.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("fragment_2 : " + key);
        Log.e("Hashmap2", String.valueOf(insureApplicantStep2));
    }
    return insureApplicant2;
}
```

All fragments' editText will be filled after the editText is valid and typing by user and send to the function and stored in HashMap.

For example: (AddTextChangedListener with TextWatcher)

```
residentAddress.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            residentAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocus){
                    if(!isFocus){
                        if("".trim().equals(residentAddress.getText().toString())){
                            rAddress.setError("Resident Address is required.");
                            strAddress = "";
                            insureApplicant2.put(2, strAddress);
                        } else {
                            rAddress.setErrorEnabled(false);
                            rAddress.setError(null);
                            strAddress = residentAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                            insureApplicant2.put(2, strAddress);

                            onPassValueStep2(insureApplicant2);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature in the `Fragment` of your interface's methods are wrong. You declared the interface like:

```
public interface onPassValue{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1();
}

public interface onPassValue2{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2();
}
```

and in the Fragment you have public

```
public Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1(HashMap insureResult) {
```

`Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2(HashMap insureApplicantStep2){`

as you can notice, the methods declared in your interfaces have no parameters.

You can either change your the method declaration in your interface, adding the missing parameter, or change the methods in the `Fragment`

Comment: Thanks for help. I made a careless mistake here. :') And how can I call those HashMap value by button click? @Blackbelt Does declare HashMap on activity and call getHashMapStep1.onPassValueStep1(insureApplicant)...... on activity onClick event?

Comment: you have to modify the interfaces. For instance `Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1(Map<Object, String> insureResult);` (do the same for the other).

Comment: only modify the instances in the interface of activity?? Thank you.

Comment: `public interface onPassValue{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep1((Map<Object, String> insureResult);
}`

Comment: `public interface onPassValue2{
    Map<Object, String> onPassValueStep2(Map<Object, String> insureResult);
}`

Comment: Thank you @Blackbelt. Also I need to change fragment's onPassValueStep1 / 2() method with this "structure"?

Comment: it might be the case